# How to get facebook profile picture usable With GD

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, gd

How can i use `https://graph.facebook.com/744595326681559/picture?width=720&;height=720` as layer?

```
<?php

$bgFile = __DIR__ . "/background-layer-1.png"; // 93 x 93
$imageFile = __DIR__ . "/icon-layer-2.png"; // 76 x 76
$watermarkFile = ('https://graph.facebook.com/744595326681559/picture?width=720&;height=720'); 

// We want our final image to be 76x76 size
$x = $y = 240;

// dimensions of the final image
$final_img = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);

// Create our image resources from the files
$image_1 = imagecreatefrompng($bgFile);
$image_2 = imagecreatefrompng($imageFile);
$image_3 = imagecreatefrompng($watermarkFile);

// Enable blend mode and save full alpha channel
imagealphablending($final_img, true);
imagesavealpha($final_img, true);

// Copy our image onto our $final_img
imagecopy($final_img, $image_1, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x, $y);
imagecopy($final_img, $image_2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x, $y);
imagecopy($final_img, $image_3, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x, $y);

ob_start();
imagepng($final_img);
$watermarkedImg = ob_get_contents(); // Capture the output
ob_end_clean(); // Clear the output buffer

header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $watermarkedImg; // outputs: `http://i.imgur.com/f7UWKA8.png`
imagepng($final_img, 'final_img1.png');
```

Comment: What is the end result of what you’re trying to achieve? What happens with the image? Is it saved, displayed on screen, used in the FB Sharer dialog?

Comment: used in the fb sharer dialog
I made the function, But Idk how to Get facebook Profile picture usable with GD, i will edit the question Right now.

Comment: I changed the question

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues using imagecreatefrompng for the Facebook Profile image. Firstly, we're assuming that the image returned from Facebook is a PNG (if it isn't, it will fail) and secondly a pitfall in loading network resources using imagecreatefrom functions are that it won't follow any redirects. Facebook 301 redirects to a longer URL so this isn't picked up. My suggestion would be to use cURL to fetch the image data from Facebook and use that.

Something like:

```
<?php

$bgFile = __DIR__ . "/background-layer-1.png"; // 93 x 93
$imageFile = __DIR__ . "/icon-layer-2.png"; // 76 x 76
$watermarkFile = 'https://graph.facebook.com/744595326681559/picture?width=720&height=720'; 


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $watermarkFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$out = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


// We want our final image to be 76x76 size
$x = $y = 240;

// dimensions of the final image
$final_img = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);

// Create our image resources from the files
$image_1 = imagecreatefrompng($bgFile);
$image_2 = imagecreatefrompng($imageFile);
$image_3 = imagecreatefromstring($out);


// Enable blend mode and save full alpha channel
imagealphablending($final_img, true);
imagesavealpha($final_img, true);

// Copy our image onto our $final_img
imagecopy($final_img, $image_1, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x, $y);
imagecopy($final_img, $image_2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x, $y);
imagecopy($final_img, $image_3, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x, $y);

ob_start();
imagepng($final_img);
$watermarkedImg = ob_get_contents(); // Capture the output
ob_end_clean(); // Clear the output buffer

header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $watermarkedImg; // outputs: `http://i.imgur.com/f7UWKA8.png`
imagepng($final_img, 'final_img1.png');

?>
```

I'm not entirely convinced the output is what you're expecting so feel free to clarify what you need and I'll try my best.